# problems with git and heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm having a double problem: one with the git: how do I remove all the .rb ~ files? and another one with the heroku: how do I do a push to a specific url? for example, I have this http://morning-day-54.heroku.com but I do git push heroku master and there is no change in this url.

Comment: ok, but I already did the git commit -a...I want a command to remove all the *.~ files...and the problem with heroku? how do I solve it.

Comment: can you show the output of a git remote -v. The remote named 'heroku' that will be listed will show the URL of the git repo that it is being pushed into. If this doesn't resemble morning-day-54 then this is where your problem lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stage the removal of one of those files for the next commit, you could do:

```
git rm foo.rb~
```

.... or to stage the removal of many such backup files in a single directory, you could do:

```
git rm *~
```

To stage the removal of all backup files in the repository, you should use `find` and `xargs` - for example:

```
find . -name '*~' -print0 | xargs -0 git rm
```

After you've staged all the removals, you should commit that with:

```
git commit -m "Remove all backup files"
```

... and to stop them being tracked in the future, add them to your `.gitignore`, for example:

```
echo '*~' >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Ignore all backup files"
```

On your Heroku question, there's really not enough information for someone to be able to work out what's going wrong.  Since that's really a separate issue, I'd suggest that you start a new question for that, but make sure that you list exactly the commands you're trying and any errors that you get.

Answer (score 0):

Using `git remove` you should be able to remove files from the repo.

Also heroku urls are randomly generated, you cant choose them unless you use the custom domain addon.

Comment: Is `git remove` a personal alias? `git rm` is the normal command.

Comment: when you create an app if you specify the name eg heroku create myappnamehere then provided myappnamehere is unique on Heroku then your app will be available on myappnamehere.heroku.com

Comment: Sorry I did mean git rm. 
John I was not aware of that - but Im sure once you have created the app you cant change it without starting a new one